# Authentic Engine Oil online

Tags: engine, oil-change

Generally at Car service centers I observed that they buy huge barrels of Engine Oil. I don't trust, what they are putting in my car. So, I purchased an engine oil can online (See picture).

My question: How do I find out it is original Mobil Super? Excuse me, if it is not the correct forum to ask such question. But I couldn't think of any other place to get expert advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Authentic" in the title? In the body of the question, what do you mean by "original?" The label on the oil you've purchased says it was manufactured in India by "Exxon/Mobil Lubricants Private Limited By: LSR Specialty Oils Private Limited."  Looks to me like Exxon/Mobile says this is "Mobile Super." Oils are often physically manufactured by subcontractors; that appears to have occured here. Does this oil's specifications meet the oil specifications required for your car? What's your actual question?

Comment: You could always google the Customer Feedback Number to check authenticity of the number, then call it to see what gives. Ask Exxon/Mobil how to verify if it's authentic or not.

Comment: It is economics; the larger the container , the lower  the unit  cost of the product . Same product in a railroad car as a one quart container.

Comment: Called their number but it go through to the customer care. Twitted Mobil1 with same picture but no response. As per car's handbook it should be SAE 0W-20. If I get it refilled by service center they triple of what it is mentioned on this can, that too from the barrel. Don't know what's inside the barrel, maybe 5W-30, because 5W-30 is more popular in Delhi/NCR. I don't want to be in situation where I paid triple the price and didn't get right food for my car.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you put the oil in a fancy shaped and colored container, which may cost more than the oil itself.

Do you think the design of those pretty finger-grips on the handle and the bottle make any difference to they way your engine works? Of course not. But if the packaging was made by Mobil, that makes you believe the contents were also made by them.

If a garage buys exactly the same stuff in a plain 40-gallon drum, the marketing magic didn't work for you.

I used to live near one of the major oil refineries in the UK. It was amusing when you drove past it to see road tankers distributing 20 "different brands of gasoline" queuing to fill up from the same storage tank.

Comment: This can't be an answer because it basically talks about how right/wrong I am on asking this question. However, I went to the service center and found that they are not putting SAE 0W-20 in any of their cars at all. As per them only Mercedez, Porsche, BMWs would require such thin quality premiere synthetic oil. If I wouldn't have investigated I would have gotten get wrong oil in my car. Now when I know for sure I want to go with fancy can, **but is fancy can bought online is real or fake.**. That was my question, you mould it to something else.